# SVM Dual Formulation :: KKT Constraint

Tags: machine-learning, svm

In Andew Ng's SVM course notes, the final hard margin optimization problem is given as the following:

[image]

I am unclear how to see from this where the 5th constraint is satisfied.

The definition of $g_{i}$ is as follows:

[image]

Can anyone help explain?

[image]

Comment: What does $g_i$ represent?

Comment: The full lecture notes are here: http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf

Comment: I added above specifically what is $g_{i}$.

Comment: I am thinking this constraint (5) that either $a_{i}$ or  $g_{i}$ must be zero, has to do with the Lagrangian dual but what I am not seeing is how that constraint is embodied in the optimization problem he has written.